# Does a multiclass character get to pick which hit dice they recover after a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, healing, rests, hit-dice

This question came up in our last game.

In 5e, after a long rest you get to recover half your hit dice.  My assumption would be is that if you are multiclass you get to pick the hit dice you want to recover.

In theory you get to pick the hit dice you want to recover even if you are not multiclass - it just doesn't matter.

Any reason to think this is not the case?

Related to
[What order do multiclass characters spend Hit Dice at the end of a short rest?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47195/what-order-do-multiclass-characters-spend-hit-dice-at-the-end-of-a-short-rest)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the linked one is abour spending hit die during a short rest.  This one is about recovering spent hit die during a long rest.

Comment: I completely overlooked that, my apologies! I have reopened it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no method specified. The *PHB* indicates you should track them separately in *Multiclassing*, under "Hit Points and Hit Dice" (p163). It has no detail on an order you must spend them, nor the order in which you recover them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61331/discussion-on-answer-by-t-j-l-does-a-multiclass-character-get-to-pick-which-hit).

Answer (score 1):

As a DM, based on how it is written I would allow the player to choose which Hit Dice to recover.  There doesn't seem to be anything to contradict that.

As a player, I would track them separately and recover 1/2 of each type instead of trying to optimize this.  Simply because it feels like it's the correct way to do it.